# Binary to hexadecimal in Swift

Tags: swift, binary, hex

I have a string in binary (for example "00100100"), and I want it in hexadecimal (like "24").

Is there a method written to convert Binary to Hexadecimal in Swift?

Comment: I'd be very surprised, but its not hard to do if you cut up the string into 4-character chunks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
func binToHex(bin : String) -> String {
    // binary to integer:
    let num = bin.withCString { strtoul($0, nil, 2) }
    // integer to hex:
    let hex = String(num, radix: 16, uppercase: true) // (or false)
    return hex
}
```

This works as long as the numbers fit into the range of `UInt` (32-bit or 64-bit,
depending on the platform). It uses the BSD library function [strtoul()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strtoul.3.html) which converts a string to an integer according to a given base.

For larger numbers you have to process the input
in chunks. You might also add a *validation* of the input string.

**Update for Swift 3/4:** The `strtoul` function is no longer needed.
Return `nil` for invalid input:

```
func binToHex(_ bin : String) -> String? {
    // binary to integer:
    guard let num = UInt64(bin, radix: 2) else { return nil }
    // integer to hex:
    let hex = String(num, radix: 16, uppercase: true) // (or false)
    return hex
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous downvoter, who reminded me to update the code for the current Swift :)

Comment: What if i want to convert 80 char long string to Hex e.g. "10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" , it wont allow beyond 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
let binaryInteger = 0b1 
// Your binary number
let hexadecimalNum = String(binaryInteger, radix: 16) 
// convert into string format in whatever base you want
```

For more information

```
let decimalInteger = 15       // prefix NONE
let binaryInteger = 0b10001   // prefix 0b
let octalInteger = 0o21       // prefix 0o
let hexadecimalInteger = 0x11 // prefix 0x
```