# How to perform some arithmetic operations on binary bit number?

Tags: swift, int

I have a number like 100100010000001010001 and when I store a number in some variable like:

```
let numb =  100100010000001010001
```

it gives me the error:

> Integer literal '100100010000001010001' overflows when stored into 'Int'

I have also tried the other ways like:

```
var number:UInt64 =  100100010000001010001
```

I just want to add another number to this number. Can anyone tell me how I can do this? I also tried:

```
NSDecimalNumber(value: 100100010000001010001)
```

and it does not work either.

Comment: `0b100100010000001010001`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28526640/2442804

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift allows you to write integer literals in different bases:

- Binary: `0b100101`
- Octal: `0o47`
- Hexadecimal: `0xd4f`
- Decimal: `3456` (no prefix)

This is covered in the [Numeric Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) section of the Swift book.

So your binary number would be written as:

```
let numb = 0b100100010000001010001
```

Or you can create the `Int` from a string using a radix:

```
let numb = Int("100100010000001010001", radix: 2)
```